# MVC Authorize with dynamic roles from static setting class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize-attribute

I'm currently developing an app that needs to be used by multiple customers, This means that i have to change the roles in my authorize tags between each publish of the application.

Currently I'm storing customer specific data in a static settings class

```
public abstract class Settings
{
    public virtual string ConnectionString { get; internal set; } = "";
    public virtual string SharepointMail { get; internal set; } = "";
    public virtual string SharepointPassword { get; internal set; } = "";
    public virtual string SharepointSite { get; internal set; } = "";
    public virtual string SharepointDocumentLibrary { get; internal set; } = "";
    public virtual int ProjectId { get; internal set; }
    public virtual string SuperUserRole { get; internal set; }
    public virtual string UserRole { get; internal set; } = "";
    public virtual string ContributorRole { get; internal set; } = "";


    private static Settings _instance;
    public static Settings Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance != null)
                return _instance;

  #if DEBUG
            return _instance = new DebugSettings();
  #elif TCOTEST
            return _instance = new TcoTestSettings();
  #elif TCORELEASE
            return _instance = new TcoReleaseSettings();
  #endif
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to set the superuserrole for each configuration, but the property needs to be constant to be used as an authorize attribute.

How do i go about this?

Comment: I would create a permission management page and extend the Authorize custom attribute to make it depend on permissions, instead of roles. That way you can say: in order to do X you need permission Y.

Comment: Im using windows authentication, so the users and assignment of roles are handled by our IT Operations department. They just assign the users who needs access a role, so i dont think this would solve it

Comment: Even if you cannot control the roles, maybe you can edit the permissions for each role and handle authentication based on permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom authorize attribute

```
public class AuthorizeRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string AccessRole { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!isAuthorized)
        {
            return false;
        }
        switch (AccessRole)
        {
            case "SuperUser":
                return httpContext.User.IsInRole(Settings.Instance.SuperUserRole);
            case "User":
                return httpContext.User.IsInRole(Settings.Instance.UserRole) || httpContext.User.IsInRole(Settings.Instance.SuperUserRole);
            case "Any":
                return httpContext.User.IsInRole(Settings.Instance.ContributorRole) || httpContext.User.IsInRole(Settings.Instance.UserRole) || httpContext.User.IsInRole(Settings.Instance.SuperUserRole);
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Which i can then use like this:

```
[AuthorizeRole(AccessRole = "Any")]
```